# Parse a list of numbers in datetime in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe of transportation data.
The datetime fields are logged in this format: [2020, 12, 10, 15, 0, 5, 18000000].
How do I parse these as datetime objects?

Comment: So the df has a column that contains such lists?

Comment: In the first place, 18000000 is wrong: the number of microseconds must be < 1000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it with `*` to the `datetime.datetime` constructor and use any pandas function to apply this to every value in your `pandas.Series`.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(*[2020, 12, 10, 15, 0, 5, 18000])
datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10, 15, 0, 5, 18000)
```

One additional moment: you will need to update microsecond field.
E.g.

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"example": [[2020, 12, 10, 15, 0, 5, 18000000]]})
df.example = df.example.apply(lambda x: datetime(
    *(v if i != len(x) - 1 else v // 1000 for i, v in enumerate(x))
))
```